# $y=\cos(m \arcsin x)$ Validity of solution $\dfrac {dy} {dx}$ when $x=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$y=\cos(m \arcsin x)$, for $ -1 < x < 1$

I want to find the value of $\dfrac {dy} {dx}$ when $x=0$
using the following way:
$=> \arccos y = m\arcsin x$
$=> - \dfrac {1} {\sqrt {1-y^2}} \dfrac {dy} {dx}= m \dfrac {1} {\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Now $x=0 => y=1$ the above equation is not valid.

But when I square both side and rearrange it: i.e.
$(1-x^2)(\dfrac {dy} {dx})^2 = m^2 (1-y^2)$
Now I can put $x=0, y=1$ and it gives a valid value.

But the final valid equation is deduced from the equation that is not valid in the first place,

For e.g. I multipled both sides by $(1-y^2)$ which leads to $\dfrac {0}{0}$ in the LHS.

So does that mean the final form is also invalid and I should not use its value?

Comment: Why don't you just compute $dy/dx$ using the chain rule directly? The you get something which automatically is valid in the whole interval $-1 < x < 1$ (where $\arcsin x$ is differentiable).

Comment: I have solved it that way when I did the question, I was wondering any other alternatives to this and came across this. And this way is marginally better when we consider $\frac {d^3y}{dx^3}$ and onwards.

Comment: Note that as $\cos(x)$ is an even function you have $\arccos y = \pm m \arcsin x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can differentiate the expression as follows
$$\frac{d}{dx}(cos^{-1}y)=\frac{d}{dx}(msin^{-1}x)$$
$$\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
So far, before substituting directly $x=0$ in the above expression is not valid Since it is given that independent variable $x=0$ hence it must be first expressed explicitly in terms of variable $x$ as follows 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\sqrt{\frac{1-y^2}{1-x^2}}=-\sqrt{\frac{1-cos^2(msin^{-1}x)}{1-x^2}}$$
Now, substituting $x=0$ in the above expression, we can simply get the valid value

$$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)_{x=0}=-\sqrt{\frac{1-cos^2(msin^{-1}(0))}{1-(0)^2}}=-\frac{0}{1}=0$$

Comment: When you express explicitly in terms of variable x in the 3rd step, you multipled both sides by $\sqrt {1-y^2}$, but since we know that $1-y^2 = 0 $ are we allowed to do that?

Comment: As I know that the substitution of the numerical values is done only after simplification i.e. in the final step, while the numerical substitution in the intermediate step is not valid I think as I have not done such numerical substitutions in the intermediate step. $y^2=1$ is allowed only after simplification. This is often seen in the problems of limit & continuity.

Answer (score 1):

for $x$ small, you have $$sin^{-1} x = x + \cdots, \cos(mx) = 1 - \frac 12 m^2 x^2+\cdots $$ so that $$\cos(m\sin^{-1}x)=\cos(mx + \cdots)=1 - \frac 12 m^2 x^2+\cdots$$

that gives you $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\cos(m\sin^{-1}x)\right)\vert_{x=0} = 0,  \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(\cos(m\sin^{-1}x)\right)\vert_{x=0} = - m^2$$